# Add private key file to Pageant from Azure local storage resource

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services, pageant

I'm implementing a Cloud Service (worker role) application in Azure which can add private key files to Pageant from an Azure Local Storage.  The `p` variable is a `Process` which starts `cmd.exe` as well.

```csharp
var filename = "pageant.exe";

var workerRoleStorageName = "PrivateKeys";
var privatekeyfilename = "ThePrivateKey.ppk";
var localResource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource(workerRoleStorageName);
var path = Path.Combine(localResource.RootPath, privatekeyfilename);

p.StandardInput.WriteLine(filename + " "+ path);
```

I'm in local now, so the content of the `path` variable is something like this:

> c:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\4691e8f6-fdbd-42ad-af67-986b491aca89\directory\PrivateKeys\ThePrivateKey.ppk

But at the last line of code I have got the following error message:

> Couldn't load this key (unable to open file).

It's quite interesting, because if I set up a hard coded simple path it works fine:

```csharp
var path = @"E:\PrivateKeys\ThePrivateKey.ppk";
```

I know that the Azure Local Storage folder is hidden in this case, so I tried to set the `E:\PrivateKeys` folder to hidden, but it still worked with the hard coded path.

What do you think, why I can't add this file to Pageant from that path?

Comment: What do you get, if you try something like `...WriteLine("dir " + path)`?

Comment: Interesting, I have got no result for that command, just the flashing cursor.

Comment: Is it different with `dir E:\PrivateKeys\ThePrivateKey.ppk`?

Comment: No, it's the same, but at my p.OutputDataReceived I can see the result of the dir commnand, with a latency. So I can list the content of that dir with the dir command.

Comment: Well, that's what I was asking for actually. So `dir` works even for the `path`? Or just for `E:\PrivateKeys\ThePrivateKey.ppk`?

Comment: Yes, dir works for the path also.

Comment: OK, and if you do `"type " + path`?

Comment: I got an 'Access is denied' message. I have to run the cmd as administrator from code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pageant is unfortunately not very informative when failing to load a private key. It reports *"Couldn't load this key (unable to open file)."* for any error, including non existence and lack or read permissions.

As is clear from your comments, in this particular instance, it's lack of permissions.

I suppose you need to run your application with higher privileges or with an appropriate role. I would not expect you can run just the `cmd.exe` with higher privileges from a less privileged process.